# Compiling C++ with boost all linux distributions

Tags: c++, linux, boost, distribution

Whats the best way to compile for all distributions with boost? I've read many articles but can't really get a hold of how to do it. I'm using code blocks and my program works on the system i build it on but not on other distros I just get a Segmentation fault (core dumped) I'm a beginner with Linux C++. below are the includes I'm using. Do I need to make a makefile? Which I don't know how to make and install on each distribution. Basically the best way to distribute the program and still having it hidden. Thanks in advance

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/regex/v4/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
```

Comment: What platforms? In Linux it's really best to build your code on the platforms directly, because of the mix of libraries like `libstdc++.so`.

Comment: You can link the compiled boost libraries (there aren't that many anyway) *statically*. I've done this with great success recently. You can even add `libstdc++` statically, too (`-static-libstdc++`), and then your code *only* depends on the runtime C library, which is far more stable across Linux distributions than the other two.

Comment: im using ubuntu 11 with code blocks, I just did a basic program and was able to move the exec to other servers and it worked i think i just need to break apart my program and find whats causing the segmentation fault core dumped error, probably something newbie i did

Comment: @user1054513: One of the big issues with C++ is linking. A dynamically linked C++ program will largely only work on the environment it's been compiled for. :-(

Comment: @user1054513:  Compile the program with `g++ -g -Wall `..., run it under `gdb` to a segfault, and then show us the `bt` (backtrace) output.

Comment: when i try to compile it i get this /tmp/ccm8fJiO.o: In function `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)':
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex.hpp:379: undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
 trying to figure out how to add in regex librarys any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are 2 ways to do this. Statically and dynamically. You can either link everything statically, and you'll be fine, if a bit wasteful with the resources. Or you can link dynamically to the specific libboost-regex.so.41.2.2 or whatever the current version is. In the latter case, you probably want to include the version you are using, prefix it to ldd with LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

I know that is somewhat high level. To be more specific, I need more details. What does ldd your-program (the thing you run) say? Likely, the problem is that boost is a bit different in the so-versioning scheme than the usual, we-only-break-ABI-on-the-first-version-number scheme. If you have some sort of a build file (I don't know code blocks), that would be nice to see, too.